# How to convert float array to java.nio.Buffer for glVertexPointer?

Tags: java, nio, libgdx

I am using libgdx and have following code

```
    float[] x;
    ...
    Buffer vVertices=x;//what to do here?
    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vVertices);
```

But I am not sure how I can pass array x to Buffer? Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(x.length * Float.BYTES); //4 bytes per float
byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
FloatBuffer buffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
buffer.put(x);
buffer.position(0);
```

Both ByteBuffer and FloatBuffer inherit from Buffer.

Answer (score 4):

You should do that:

```
FloatBuffer vVertices = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(x);
vVertices.rewind();
```

It works fine with JOGL 2.0: 
[static FloatBuffer     newDirectFloatBuffer(float[] values)](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/gluegen/javadoc/com/jogamp/common/nio/Buffers.html#newDirectFloatBuffer%28float%5B%5D%29)

If you still use JOGL 1, this helper is in the class com.sun.opengl.util.BufferUtil.

The best solution consists in using the method in LIBGDX:
[static java.nio.FloatBuffer    newFloatBuffer(int numFloats)](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/BufferUtils.html#newFloatBuffer%28int%29)